# Is there a way to specify an arbitrary time to start an azure scheduled job?

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler, azure-management-portal

Currently from the Azure portal (old portal) when setting up a scheduled job start time, you can only specify times as half hour intervals like 12:00 or 3:30 but you can't tell it to start from say 12:55.  Is there another way to set up a scheduled job that allows for any start time?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the new portal, which enables you more advanced options along side with the ability to set the scheduling to a minute granularity. Or use the [REST api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn528937.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to do a request with a specific time/interval.

Hope this helps!

Mert